# Typeinfo how to get the name/id of the class in a polymorphic collection?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, rtti, typeid

In the following example I would expect not stdout : `Base Foo Bar`, but I get `P4Base P4Base P4Base`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Base {};
class Foo : public Base {};
class Bar : public Base {};

using Collection = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> >;

int main() {
    Collection collection;
    collection.push_back(std::make_unique<Base>());
    collection.push_back(std::make_unique<Foo>());
    collection.push_back(std::make_unique<Bar>());
    for (auto &u:collection)
        std::cout << typeid(u.get()).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a way to properly identify which kind of instance I have in my collection?

**EDIT**

A Working example after the advice of [eerorika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2079303/eerorika)

```
struct Base {virtual ~Base() = default;};
struct Foo : public Base {};
struct Bar : public Base {};

using Collection = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> >;

int main() {
    Collection collection;
    collection.push_back(std::make_unique<Base>());
    collection.push_back(std::make_unique<Foo>());
    collection.push_back(std::make_unique<Bar>());
    for (auto &u:collection)
        std::cout << typeid(*u).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: _"Is there a way to properly identify which kind of instance I have in my collection?"_ You shouldn't need to do that. Use _interfaces_ and an _abstract_ base class instead. That's more a question of proper design.

Comment: Though there is the issue of serialization, in which `typeid` can become useful. Though if you're going to be switching based on the type of the object, why not just make it one type with an enum member and switch on that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do you mean adding an attribute on each class to identify which on it is?

Comment: Read the caveats for [type_info::name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name). The results can border on useless.

Comment: @nowox No, I meant what I said. Store  _abstract interfaces_  in that vector implement those interfaces as needed with `Foo` and `Bar`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is still confusing for me. From my understanding an interface is an abstract class and I don't think I can do `vectort<AbstractClass>`. Do you have a clue?

Comment: @nowox But you can do `vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractClass>>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Typeinfo how to get the name/id of the class in a polymorphic collection?

- Firstly, the classes must be polymorphic in order for `typeid` to provide the dynamic type. Your classes are not polymorphic, so you would get the static type.
- Secondly, you must use an lvalue to the pointed object instead of a pointer. Applying `typeid` to a pointer gives you the type info of the pointer type rather than type of the pointed object.
- Thirdy, the behaviour of your program is undefined because derived objects are destroyed through pointer to base with non-virtual destructor.

To fix first and third point, provide a virtual destructor for the base. To fix second:

```
typeid(*u).name()
```

Lastly, your expectation of readable class names is misguided. `std::type_info::name` is not guaranteed to give you the name as you have written it for the class. The result is implementation defined, and in practice you typically get the mangled name of the type. There is no standard way to get a readable name, but there are implementation defined ways to demangle names.

Comment: In the end, I would like to use `dynamic_cast` but I still not figured out how to use it to get a reference on `Foo` or `Bar`

Comment: @nowox Like this `if (Foo* p = dynamic_cast<Foo*>(collection[1].get()))`. That said, most uses of `dynamic_cast` are better implemented by using virtual functions instead.

Answer (score 4):

The output you are seeing is caused by the fact that the `u` variable is `auto` deduced to *always* be a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` type.

One way of fixing this is to add `virtual` members to your classes that return the `typeid` of their respective `this` pointers. Then, each call to that function on the `u` pointer will call the *actual* derived class override:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    virtual const char* name() { return typeid(this).name(); }
};
class Foo : public Base {
public:
    const char* name() override { return typeid(this).name(); }
};
class Bar : public Base {
public:
    const char* name() override { return typeid(this).name(); }
};

using Collection = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> >;

int main()
{
    Collection collection;
    collection.push_back(std::make_unique<Base>());
    collection.push_back(std::make_unique<Foo>());
    collection.push_back(std::make_unique<Bar>());
    for (auto& u : collection)
        std::cout << u->name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only need to put the `name()` member function in the `Base` class.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 If I comment-out the `name` members in the derived classes, the output is three times this: `class Base * __ptr64`. With the code as shown, the second output is (as expected) `class Foo * __ptr64` and the third different again.

Comment: So `typeid(this)` written in a `Base` member function doesn't recognize dynamic type? Hmm. Could be an optimization thing.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 Possibly. Using `typeid(*this).name();` - thus forcing a dereference - works, though. But I wasn't sure if OP wanted the object name or the pointer name.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues.

1. `u.get()` has a type "pointer to Base". If you want to print the type of the object itself, try `typeid(*u.get()).name()`.
2. If you want polymorphic behaviour, use polymorphic classes. This requires defining at least one virtual function in `Base`. You need to define a virtual destructor anyway for correct behaviour of object deletion. Without one, the program has UB.
3. `name()` returns an implementation-defined string, so you cannot expect `Base Foo Bar`. You might get something similar though if you fix the other problems. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/11fYfa).

Answer (score 1):

The expression `typeid(var).name()` for variable `var` should be unique among different types. However, for indexing and general distinguishing use you should use `typeid(var).hash_code()`.